# How to add round controller in Phaser 2 game

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

i tried to find the solution in the library.
i find a game in github https://github.com/knagaitsev/slither.io-clone
i change many thing to this game to make it more advance but now i want to add game controller like this image in this game https://i.gyazo.com/8f31c8c886c6c818bcb9ededf95cd594.png

right now its very easy to play in pc by mouse and up down arrow keys. but i want to add controller also

Comment: Do you have a controller?  Have you investigated the make and model?  Most game controllers have a standardized interface.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this example](https://samme.github.io/phaser-examples-mirror/input/gamepad%20multiple%20pads.html), it shows how to use Controllers in Phaser 2. You should also checkout [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/#toc-23).

> I recommend switching to **phaser 3**, this would mean some rewriting, but it will make development faster and easier, in the long run.